# Auto insert with rule Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a query re a flexi-time recording spreadsheet I am using.
I want to automatically insert a value from 2 cells in 1 worksheet to 2 cells in another worksheet but I need to include a rule that if the value is more than 14 hours it automatically corrects to 14 only.
Is this possible, if so can you let me have the correct formula to use please?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer. If A1 held the time difference in hours, then =Min(14,a1) will return 14 if a1 was larger than 14, else you get the actual difference of A1.  A similar method could be used if you were working with vba and not formulas.

Answer (score 0):

It is batter to show the layout of  your worksheet

Anyway try something like this

```
=if(cell_refernce>14,14,cell_reference)
```